# I have a problem with a Instagram like bot with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

Hey guys I am new into python, I learned java and Pascal and yea I wanted to learn how to use instagram bots with python and watched a youtube video, but my problem is that the bot just picks pictures and switches to the next one without liking it, so I think it can't find the like button.

I think the problem is somewhere at # Liking photos
I tried changing the xpath a lot of times but it doesn't end up liking a picture.
Thanks in advance

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import random
import sys


def print_same_line(text):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.flush()


class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(3)
       #login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/accounts/login/']")
       #login_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
        user_name_elem.clear()
        user_name_elem.send_keys(self.username)
        passworword_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
        passworword_elem.clear()
        passworword_elem.send_keys(self.password)
        passworword_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)


    def like_photo(self, hashtag):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + hashtag + "/")
        time.sleep(2)

        # gathering photos
        pic_hrefs = []
        for i in range(1, 4):
            try:
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                time.sleep(2)
                # get tags
                hrefs_in_view = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
                # finding relevant hrefs
                hrefs_in_view = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in hrefs_in_view
                                 if '.com/p/' in elem.get_attribute('href')]
                # building list of unique photos
                [pic_hrefs.append(href) for href in hrefs_in_view if href not in pic_hrefs]
                # print("Check: pic href length " + str(len(pic_hrefs)))
            except Exception:
                continue

        # Liking photos
        unique_photos = len(pic_hrefs)
        for pic_href in pic_hrefs:
            driver.get(pic_href)
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            try:
             time.sleep(random.randint(2, 4))
             #I think the problem is somewhere at the xpath
             like_button = lambda:  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button/span[@aria-label='Like']").click()
             like_button().click()
             time.sleep(2)

                for second in reversed(range(0, random.randint(18, 28))):
                    print_same_line("#" + hashtag + ': unique photos left: ' + str(unique_photos)
                                    + " | Sleeping " + str(second))
                   time.sleep(1)
            except Exception as e:
                time.sleep(2)
            unique_photos -= 1

if __name__ == "__main__":

    username = "USERNAME"
    password = "PASSWORD"

    enesIG = InstagramBot("myIGloginname", "myIGPassword")
    enesIG.login()
    enesIG.like_photo('newyork')

    hashtags = ['amazing', 'beautiful', 'adventure', 'photography', 'nofilter',
                'newyork', 'artsy', 'alumni', 'lion', 'best', 'fun', 'happy',
                'art', 'funny', 'me', 'followme', 'follow', 'cinematography', 'cinema',
                'love', 'instagood', 'instagood', 'followme', 'fashion', 'sun', 'scruffy',
                'street', 'canon', 'beauty', 'studio', 'pretty', 'vintage', 'fierce']

    while True:
        try:
            # Choose a random tag from the list of tags
            tag = random.choice(hashtags)
            ig.like_photo(tag)
        except Exception:
            ig.closeBrowser()
            time.sleep(60)
            enesIG = InstagramBot(username, password)
            enesIG.login()
```

The current Error is this one. And when I change the xpath on the like button there are other errors.

```
C:\Python38-32>Instagram_Bot3.py
  File "C:\Python38-32\Instagram_Bot3.py", line 78
    for second in reversed(range(0, random.randint(18, 28))):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Did you try **looking at the code, as it appears in the post**? See how it is strangely indented, around the point where the error was reported? See how that might correspond to an `IndentationError`?

Answer (score 0):

Give this xpath a shot

```
//*[name()='svg'][@aria-label='Like']/parent::button
```

What you were trying to access as a `span` is actually an `svg` element, so this seems to find it accurately. You may run into some other issues. When testing locally I ended up using

```
like_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg'][@aria-label='Like']/parent::button")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", like_button)
```

Which uses javascript to click the 'like' button. This seems to work fairly reliably.

Also, that error you referenced is solely due to how your code is formatted. I was able to fix that when testing your code locally by copying the whitespace before the line above it and pasting it into that line, but you *really* should use tabs consistently. Mixing tabs and spaces can get annoying with Python.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the right xpath. I also fixed my error by formatting it rightly. The Javascript Idea is also good, but when I tried it, the same happens again. It doesn't like the picture. I have it on record what it looks like. I you have time give it a look please :) https://streamable.com/6faznj